# How can i access specific value in a HashMap?

Tags: java

This simple game asks for the number of the players and their names and counts their score.How can i get the player with the highest score?

**main:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String,Integer> players= new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    System.out.printf("Give the number of the players: ");
    int numOfPlayers = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int k=1;k<=numOfPlayers;k++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Give the name of player %d: ",k);
        String nameOfPlayer= scanner.next();
        players.put(nameOfPlayer,0);//score=0
    }

    //This for finally returns the score
    for(String name:players.keySet())
    {
          System.out.println("Name of player in this round: "+name);
          //::::::::::::::::::::::
          //::::::::::::::::::::::


          int score=players.get(name)+ p.getScore();;

          //This will update the corresponding entry in HashMap
          players.put(name,score);
          System.out.println("The Player "+name+" has "+players.get(name)+" points ");
    }
}
```

This what i tried myself:

```
Collection c=players.values(); 
System.out.println(Collections.max(c));
```

Comment: You already have an example of how to iterate through all of the entries in your map and get the score for each player.  Do you not know how to do numeric comparison?  What have you tried yourself?

Comment: What is `p.getScore()` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collections.max()` to get the maximum value of the Collection of hashmap entries obtained by `HashMap.entrySet()` with custom comparator for comparing values.

Example:

```
    HashMap<String,Integer> players= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    players.put("as", 10);
    players.put("a", 12);
    players.put("s", 13);
    players.put("asa", 15);
    players.put("asaasd", 256);
    players.put("asasda", 15);
    players.put("asaws", 5);
    System.out.println(Collections.max(players.entrySet(),new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }));
```

You can modify above code to best meet your condition.

Comment: Which would get you the highest score, but not the player with the highest score.  If you want to use `Collections.max()` you need to do it on `entrySet()` not `values()` and you would need to write a custom comparator.

Comment: @MarkPeters : didn't seen that OP wants player name.

Comment: @MarkPeters: Now I think answer is rite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...This what i tried myself(because you ask on your comment):Collection c=players.values();
        System.out.println(Collections.max(c));

Comment: @nick: Now I have used `players.entrySet() `instead of `players.values()`.